# Metric to compare function similarity

Tags: functions, regression

I have 3 functions (built by x,y values: [CSV file link](https://mega.nz/file/mE4yULTS#PMNJlgXc25njQ8GLRAxBWHpvaMeim_plKgu5K-Nz4xw)).

[image: Three mathematical functions]

The red one is a baseline function. The green and blue ones are approximated versions of the red ones. It is clear that the green one is much more similar to the red one and the blue one is a very aggressive function with many overshoots.

I want to find a metric that will show that. So, the similarity score between green and red will be higher than between blue and red so this metric will show the aggressiveness.

Both green and blue are slightly above the red one, so if I use RMS, the similarity of the blue and green to the red one is the same, and it doesn't reflect the overshoot aggressiveness.

Which metric can I use to evaluate the functions' similarity to the baseline function?

Comment: Why not the MSE or MSRE or MSAE or etc.? This depends on what one actualy want. If you joint data instead of graph one could answer more concretely.

Comment: @JJacquelin I added a link to my data (CSV file). I'm trying to find the similarity to the baseline function and some metric that will demonstrate the aggressiveness of the function (the frequency of the overshoot peaks). MSE for example, gets a lower (better) value when the function is more aggressive (with same amplitude). Which should be exactly the opposite

Comment: I cannot load the data. Error : "The transfer you requested has been deleted".

Comment: @JJacquelin uploaded again via another provider. Please retry. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

Following your comment, maybe you can try the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test-based criteria, i.e.,

$$
D = \sup_x| F_{1, n}(x) - F_{2, n}(x)|.
$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how I can use it with my data. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to well understand the problem. Nevertheless I post below a few tests. Hoping that will help.

From data : Red y0(x)=Baseline ; Blue y1(x)=funct1 ; Green y2(x)=funct2 ; Brown y3(x)=func3 :

[image]

Difference between each function and the Baseline : Blue (y1-y0) ; Green (y2-y0) ; Brown (y3-y0) :

[image]

Visually it is obvious that the difference is lower for funct2 than for func1 and the difference is much higher for funct3.

Probably they are many manners to characterize numerically the above difference with an even function which is equat to zero when the difference is zero. A few examples below.

[image]

The case c=2 corresponds to the Root Mean Square difference.

Other functions f(epsilon) can be chosen depending on what is expected.